# fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set when running jest tests

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I have come late to the party on writing tests (I am still learning!), and have already had a few issues running jest tests on my app. In particular, with react-navigation.

Now I am having an issue as per the below when I run npm test

> Invariant Violation: __fbBatchedBridgeConfig is not set, cannot invoke native modules
>
> ```
>  at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
>  at Object.invariant (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:162:3)
>  at Object.require [as NativeModules] (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:322:12)
>  at Object.NativeModules (node_modules/react-native-document-picker/index.js:3:30)
> ```

I have had some other problems which have been solved as per the code shown below, but give rise to this message.

My package.json is as follows:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-navigation|react-navigation-redux-helpers|@react-navigation/.*)"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "./__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "./__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
```

jsetSetup looks like this:

```
jest.mock('react-native-gesture-handler', () => {
  const View = require('react-native/Libraries/Components/View/View');
  return {
    Swipeable: View,
    DrawerLayout: View,
    State: {},
    ScrollView: View,
    Slider: View,
    Switch: View,
    TextInput: View,
    ToolbarAndroid: View,
    ViewPagerAndroid: View,
    DrawerLayoutAndroid: View,
    WebView: View,
    NativeViewGestureHandler: View,
    TapGestureHandler: View,
    FlingGestureHandler: View,
    ForceTouchGestureHandler: View,
    LongPressGestureHandler: View,
    PanGestureHandler: View,
    PinchGestureHandler: View,
    RotationGestureHandler: View,
    /* Buttons */
    RawButton: View,
    BaseButton: View,
    RectButton: View,
    BorderlessButton: View,
    /* Other */
    FlatList: View,
    gestureHandlerRootHOC: jest.fn(),
    Directions: {},
  };
});

global.__fbBatchedBridgeConfig = require('./bridge-mock');
```

I expect npm test to run the tests and provide the required output. As an aside, I'm using storybook/storyshot. I'm confused as to why the document-picker component is even relevant here, as it is not referenced in the one snapshot test I am using.

Comment: The issues _fbBatchedBridgeConfig – it has a lot to do with the packager  than the code it’s self. Also see here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090713/testing-component-that-uses-react-navigation-with-jest]
About the document -picker component – it could be relevant due to the last object of your package.json file

Comment: Thanks - not sure where this takes me. This is the problem with knowing how to do the development work but having zero clue when it comes to what is actually happening behind the scenes...

Comment: @Carl I am having a similar issue and am wondering if you were able to solve this.

Comment: This happens with me when I have symlinks for one or more dependencies. Could you please try the following?

 yarn unlink <packageName> && yarn install --force

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when there are symlinks for one or more dependencies. Could you please try the following?

```
yarn unlink <packageName> && yarn install --force
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when jest mocks are not initialized by default for external packages that uses React Native.

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native"
      },
```

Add this to your `package.json` under `"jest"`.